# Double-check that you’re using the right type of org

Tags: trailhead

trailhead challenge of wave analytics :
Double-check that you’re using the right type of org

Comment: Akhtar, what question are you trying to ask ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you started ​wave analytics module on trailhead.

Error states that you have to use a newer developer org which supports wave.

Quoting the error from trailhead module:

> **Double-check that you’re using the right type of org**
>
> To access the Wave features you need to complete Wave modules, you
>   must use a special Wave-enabled Developer Edition org. This special
>   org is required for all Wave trails; you can’t use just any old org!
>   If you created a Wave org awhile back, you may want to sign up for a
>   new one to get the latest updates. Not a very challenging challenge,
>   is it?